# crontab entry for a command to run every week and three months?

Tags: cron

What would be my `crontab` entry for a command which I want to run every week. I don't want to run any command between 8 PM till 5 AM and any random day is fine.

Similarly what would be my `crontab` entry for command which I want to run every three month, and also I don't want to run any command between 8 PM till 5 AM and any random day is fine.

Just started with `crontab` so having some difficulties

Comment: `cron.weekly` and `cron.monthly` comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`crontab` entry for every week (Monday at 3:10 pm):

```
10 15 * * 1  test -x /path/to/your/weekly/command && /path/to/your/weekly/command
```

and every 3 months, on the 2nd of January, April, July, and October at 1:12 pm:

```
12 13 2 1,4,7,10 *  test -x /path/to/your/quarterly/cmd && /path/to/your/quarterly/cmd
```

This is for a normal user's `crontab` entries , for `/etc/crontab` add the username before the command.

For commands to run weekly, on Vixie `cron`, you can also use `@weekly` instead of the first 5 entries. In that case it would run at the beginning of each Sunday at midnight (`0 0 * * 0`), which is not during the time you want.

Comment: Thanks Anthon for suggestion. In your three month example, why do you have `1,4,7,10`? What does this mean?

Comment: Those are month numbers: January = 1, April = 4, etc. Comma seperation of values matches any month number in that list. You could probably use `*/3` (any number divisible by 3 to get March, June, September and December. Use `man 5 crontab` for a full explanation.

Comment: I see. Makes sense now. I will definitely take a look at man crontab. Suppose if I need to run it every month instead of three month, then I just need to use `12 13 2 1 *` ? Is that right?

Comment: If you want to do every month `12 13 2 * *  test.....` to run on the 2nd of each month.